# Cannot install Wine (held broken packages)

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

I 'm trying to install Wine on my Ubuntu system, but cannot complete the installation. I have read countless other Q & A but none of them seems to fix my problem.
When I try to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

I get this message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried with Synaptic:
(wine package has an exclamation mark instead of a check)

```
Could not apply changes!  
Fix broken packages first.
```

I click to fix the packages and then this error occurs:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I have also tried commands like

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
sudo aptitude search wine
sudo dpkg -p Wine
```

but none of them worked as well.
I 'm so confused right now that I might be missing something simple. I 'm a new Ubuntu user, so I don 't know advanced methods and terminal commands. Am I doing something wrong? I have only tried solutions and commands posted in this forum. Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit:
After I ran

`uname -a; lsb_release -a; apt-cache policy wine wine1.6; sudo apt-get remove wine; sudo apt-get install -f`
I get:

```
Linux tommy-Lenovo-Z50-75 3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

`apt-cache policy wine wine1.6`

```
wine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
wine1.6:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
     1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

`sudo apt-get remove wine`

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'wine' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
```

`sudo apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Edit:
I tried

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge wine
$ sudo apt-get install wine
```

even after running `sudo apt-get update`. The problem remains.

Edit (last and final):
After an unsuccessful attempt to determine the broken packages, I will format my laptop to Ubuntu Gnome (latest version). Current version I run 14.04 LTS with Unity. Thanks for all your help, this thread should be closed. It seems my system is missing some packages so since it is freshly installed (2 weeks ago) I will just format it again. Thanks again for all the responses!

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `uname -a; lsb_release -a; apt-cache policy wine wine1.6; sudo apt-get remove wine; sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine` ? That might do it. Also, trying `autoremove` in place of `remove` could work.

Comment: Don't use screenshots for the output. Restart the commands again an ad the output to your question.

Comment: I agree with A.B.. You can copy and paste terminal content similar to most other GUI application.

Comment: Looking at the terminal output, it's unclear, what prevented the installation of the `wine` package. The underlying issue might have been resolved by some intermediary action. Can you try to run `sudo apt-get install wine` again and include its output in your question, please?

Comment: sorry to keep you waiting guys, I was away. Thanks for the fast responses. I 'm editing the question now.

Comment: Sorry, I see. Perhaps you should only follow one answer.

Comment: Sorry guys I do not know how am I supposed to work in these situations... I don't really have an idea of what I'm doing. I have too little experience in Ubuntu.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get purge wine; sudo apt-get install -f` Add the output here http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13247452/ (also thanks for the advice)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31510/discussion-between-a-b-and-tzatziki-xwris-kremmudi).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that what blocks wine1.7 from being installed in Ubuntu 15.10 is absence of the libgphoto2 package once I have downloaded and installed it manually I could install Wine without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Type the following into a terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge wine
$ sudo apt-get install wine
```

This should remove any held packages, and properly install Wine. Also make sure that you did not install Wine from source.

Answer (score 0):

1. You currently do not have any problem ... proved by :

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install -f
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
   ```
2. The PPA also does not have problems. There is a package `wine` for Trusty and this *should* install the package `wine1.7` Check it with this [link](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcepub/5323913/+listing-archive-extra). As having tested this on my machine it works. The package `wine` forces the installation of `wine1.7`. I'm afraid you just forgot to run the command `sudo apt-get update`. Obviously you did it in the meantime (according to your updated question).
3. The package `wine` is "only" a meta-package. You could also install `wine` with the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wine1.7
   ```

Comment: I got [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13247730/)

Comment: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386; sudo apt-get update` to add the support for 32-bit architecture. After that, restart the installation of wine.

Comment: My system is 64 bit I think, I did run the command, [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13247796/) is what I got.

Comment: The next one `sudo apt-cache policy wine1.7-i386`

Comment: Sorry, no. Updated my last comment, my thumb was to fast :)

Comment: And the 32-bit thing, read this ;) http://askubuntu.com/a/697303/367165

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13247836/

Comment: The next one `sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31513/discussion-between-tzatziki-xwris-kremmudi-and-a-b).

Answer (score 0):

This would repair the necessary links too.

```
> sudo apt-get install wine --fix-missing
```

Comment: the second command gave me a somewhat different log

Comment: What do these commands do anyway? I just got a log I posted in the question

Comment: Have a look http://paste.ubuntu.com/13247504/

Comment: **dschinn1001:** We appreciate you trying to be helpful, but please do not post questions as answers, even if they are related to the question at hand. Leave a comment or [ask a new question.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)