# Unable to install Guitar Pro 6 32bit on a 32bit system

Tags: kubuntu, libraries

I had to reinstall Kubuntu 15.10 (32bit) and when I try to reinstall Guitar Pro 6 (32bit) it failed. The strange thing is that it was working perfectly fine before with same OS, same PC, same Guitar Pro 6 .deb package.

When I try to install it I get :

```
fr2632v3@fr2632v3:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i gp6-full-linux-r11686.deb
Selecting previously unselected package guitarpro6.
(Reading database ... 215253 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gp6-full-linux-r11686.deb ...
Unpacking guitarpro6 (6.1.9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of guitarpro6:
guitarpro6 depends on libportaudio0; however:
Package libportaudio0 is not installed.
guitarpro6 depends on libssl0.9.8; however:
Package libssl0.9.8 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package guitarpro6 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:
guitarpro6
```

Then I run :

```
fr2632v3@fr2632v3:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
guitarpro6
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 109 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 216527 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing guitarpro6 (6.1.9) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
```

By checking the dependencies :

```
fr2632v3@fr2632v3:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -I gp6-full-linux-r11686.deb  
new debian package, version 2.0. 
size 55312520 bytes: control archive=34796 bytes. 
    383 bytes,    10 lines      control               
 111155 bytes,  1206 lines      md5sums               
 Package: GuitarPro6 
 Version: 6.1.9 
 Section: non-free/audio 
 Priority: optional 
 Architecture: i386 
 Depends: gksu, libasound2, libc6 (>= 2.1.3), libglu1-mesa, libportaudio0,      libportaudio2, libssl0.9.8, libstdc++6, libxml2, libxslt1.1, zlib1g 
 Installed-Size: 106346 
 Maintainer: Arobas Music <contact@arobas-music.com> 
 Description: http://www.guitar-pro.com 
  Guitar Pro 6, Linux Version.
```

I found out the the following are installed :

```
gksu
libasound2
libc6
libglu1-mesa
libportaudio2
libstdc++6
libxml2
libxslt1.1
zlib1g
```

And the issue is that the following are not found :

```
libportaudio0
libssl0.9.8
```

But :

```
fr2632v3@fr2632v3:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install libportaudio0 libssl0.9.8 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Package libssl0.9.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or 
is only available from another source 

E: Unable to locate package libportaudio0 
E: Package 'libssl0.9.8' has no installation candidate
```

Any idea how/where can I found and install libssl0.9.8 and libportaudio0 ? Btw I have contacted the Guitar Pro technical support and I have got an horrible support. Besides they are really unqualified and they couldn`t help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: A quick search on https://packages.ubuntu.com for those two packages tells me that both are not available for 15.10, but only up to Vivid (15.04). Was your previous install on 15.04 maybe? You might have to find a PPA that provides those packages in a version for 15.10 or compile them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The previous installation was a 15.10 but upgraded from the 15.04. So maybe those packages somehow remains if you upgrade ? That`s strange. I guess now its up to Guitar Pro to update the software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

- Change the dependencies
- Use older libraries

I prefer **Change the dependencies**

---

### Change the dependencies:

Follow these commands

1. Extract the DEB package

   ```
   cd
   mkdir deb$$
   cp gp6-full-linux-r11686.deb deb$$
   cd deb$$
   dpkg-deb -x gp6-full-linux-r11686.deb  deb
   cd deb
   dpkg-deb -e ../gp6-full-linux-r11686.deb
   ```
2. Change the dependencies:

   ```
   sed -i 's/libssl0\.9\.8/libssl1.0.0/' DEBIAN/control
   sed -i 's/libportaudio0/libportaudio2/' DEBIAN/control
   ```
3. Re-pack the DEB file and install

   ```
   cd ..
   sudo dpkg-deb -b deb
   sudo dpkg -i deb.deb
   ```

---

### Use the old libraries

1. Download the necessary packages, we need the [32-bit versions](https://askubuntu.com/a/697323/367165)

   ```
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/portaudio/libportaudio0_18.1-7.1_i386.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu4_i386.deb
   ```
2. Install

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libportaudio0_18.1-7.1_i386.deb libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu4_i386.deb
   sudo dpkg -i gp6-full-linux-r11686.deb
   ```

Comment: A.B. You rock! I tried first to change the dependecies, the GP6 icon shows up but wonts start up, Used the old libraries and now it works! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Nice to hear that, You're welcome. =)