# Running 32bit program on 64bit ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 64-bit, skype, 15.10, 32-bit

```
> proxychains skype
> ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
> ERROR: ld.so: object 'libproxychains.so.3' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

I am using proxychains on Ubuntu 15.10 an have googled this issue many times and cannot find it. The problem is that skype is a 32bit application and proxychains is installed as a 64bit, so it isn't able to work with skype. I have googled this issue and found no legitimate solutions.

EDIT: not only does it not work for skype, but there are other applications as well that I have that are 32bit that it doesn't work with.

I also tried googling how to run a 32bit program on Ubuntu 15.10. To be clear, I do not just need to run it, it has to be ran as a 32bit and the libraries need to be downloaded as 32bit. Since i am on 64bit and proxychains is 64bit it already runs, just not with skype. Does anyone know I can fix this and get it working without the LD_PRELOAD error?

Comment: No. The app already runs, i need to use install it as a 32bit. NOt run it. It runs perfectly fine, just not with skype or other 32bit applications ;/

Comment: You need to install and run the 32-bit version of `proxychains`. This cannot be done typically through the package manager, if you still want to retain the 64-bit version. You'll need to find a way to install both at the same time (including architecture-specific dependencies) and then set up things, so you can use something like `proxychain32 skype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the 32-bit package of `libproxychains3`

```
sudo apt-get install libproxychains3:i386
```

and read [Why are there so many 32-bit dependencies for Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/q/697301/367165).

Comment: |DNS-response|: pipe.skype.com does not exist
/usr/lib/proxychains3/proxyresolv: 16: /usr/lib/proxychains3/proxyresolv: dig: not found
are any of those errors things I should be concerned about? Skype starts up without my origional error, but i keep getting those throughout while it is running

Comment: Seems to be a different problem. Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Comment: Your comment worked for proxychains 3, but I recently installed proxychains 4 from rofl0r's github page (because it was much upgraded) and now I am getting the error:
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/libproxychains4.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
I tried installing libproxychains4:i386 but the package doesn't exist ... any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: The package is also not available for 16.04. You have to compile it.

Comment: Seems to be a bigger problem. Please ask a new question and give me the link.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/702918/compiling-32bit-program-on-64bit-ubuntu