# 15.10 - unable to run 32bit wine

Tags: wine, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have been trying to install wine on my 64bit Ubuntu 15.10 today and ran into some problems.
I installed simply by running

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Now the issue is that I can't run the wine binary, the error being the following:

```
linn@Asus:/$ wine
bash: /usr/bin/wine: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

While the 64 bit binary seems to be working just fine:

```
linn@Asus:/$ wine64
Usage: wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]   Run the specified program
       wine --help                   Display this help and exit
       wine --version                Output version information and exit
```

Now of course I started to digg around a little and it seems that the "wine" binary is indeed a 32 bit binary and I apparently need a couple of extra libraries in order to run those.

```
linn@Asus:/$ file /usr/bin/wine
/usr/bin/wine: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ca94516ed13ede12998b464b0a5ef9f5ebebfb67, stripped
```

Even though I think that any such libraries should come as dependencies when I install wine via apt-get. I still tried to install them but realized that I had all of those already and didn't make a change. (e.g. libraries suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/454254/493318) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/702235/493318))

I quite frankly don't know what to try anymore and it doesn't seem like any overly frequent issue, judging by the little amount of similar problems I could find on the web.

One other peculiar issue that might point towards something is that this is a laptop running on Swedish language packages. When I try to run winecfg, the following happens:

```
linn@Asus:/$ winecfg
/usr/bin/wine: 1: /usr/bin/wine: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Could there be any messed up paths due to some language issues?

The wine version is the following:

```
linn@Asus:/$ wine64 --version
wine-1.6.2
```

But the same issue appeared when trying the 1.7 and 1.8 versions from the official wine PPA.

Thanks for in advance for any help and effort.

**Update 1**

I have tried to remove any wine related package by running apt-get remove and autoremove on everything I could find that had to do with wine.
Checking dpkg for any wine related packages now gave me:

```
linn@Asus:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -e wine
libkwineffects6                 deinstall
libwine-development:amd64           deinstall
libwine-development:i386            deinstall
wine1.6                     deinstall
wine1.6-amd64                   deinstall
wine1.6-i386:i386               deinstall
wine1.8                     deinstall
wine1.8-amd64                   deinstall
wine1.8-i386:i386               deinstall
```

Then I tried what Gert Otten suggested in his answer and ran (i tried to install just plain "wine" instead of "wine-bin" because the package "wine-bin" doesn't seem to exist for Ubuntu 15.10):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Unfortunately it results in the same issues.

Comment: That's indeed very interesting *____* Ok, do that: create file `test.c` with the text `int main(){}`. Next execute `gcc test.c -march=i386 -m32 -o a` — that would create file `a`. Execute it like `./a`, and tell if you see any error *(ideally you wouldn't see any output at all)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the problem was that I used a custom 4.4 kernel that I needed because the touchpad on my laptop wasn't working. The issue is described in this [kernel bugzilla thread](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108581#c24).

The required changes were included in the 4.5 version of the Linux Kernel which I am running now. The moment I changed from the custom kernel to the mainline kernel, wine started to work without a problem. I then also tested with an official 4.4 mainline kernel and wine worked with that one as well. So I am pretty certain that the custom kernel was the cause of the issue, although I can't really explain how.

Hope this might help someone with similar issues.

Comment: I had the same problem with a custom kernel. The problem was solved by enabling the following two features in ´make menuconfig´:
Executable file formats / Emulation ->
* IA32 Emulation
* x32 ABI for 64-bit mode. 
I am not sure if both is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the i386 version of Wine, you can do so using these commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

After that run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine-bin
```

And lastly run:

```
winecfg
```

To test the Wine i386 version.

Comment: I tried that. Adding the architecture and the following update work fine. However, apt-get can't find any wine-bin package afterwards.

Edit: Apparently it is available for 14.04 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/wine-bin), but it doesn't seem to work on 15.10 .